# What can we put in scala class declaration?

Tags: scala

In scala, we can define a class like this:

```
class x {
     var a=10
     a = a+1
}
```

a = a + 1 is an assignment operation, usually is placed in a “function”. To my knowledge, “class” is kinda “type”, operations like this (put in a class) have some special meaning or specific usage?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put pretty much any code inside the declaration block of a `class`. This code will be executed once each time a new instance of the class is created. So the whole block is the equivalent of the **constructor** in `C`/`C++`.

However in Scala, symbols that are defined inside this constructor become members of the class, so member variables and methods are declared *inside the constructor* rather than outside as they are in `C`/`C++`. This looks odd when you first come across it, but it is very powerful and concise.

Typically the constructor is used to create member values and methods

```
class x {
    val value: Int = 42 // New member value
    def addValue(i: Int) = i + value // New method
}
```

But it can also be used to execute arbitrary code.

```
class x {
    println("Initialising my class")

    val value: Int = 42

    startUpServers()

    def addValue(i: Int) = i + value

    {
        val temp = 12 // NOT a member value

        setTemperature(temp)
    }
}
```

It is usually not necessary to have `var` members, but if you must have them then they can be modified inside the declaration block as shown in your example code.

Comment: "each new class that is created" - probably "class instance" or "object", no?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks, I have corrected the text to clarify this point.

Comment: expressions in curly braces following a class instance being created can also be treated as “constructor”, right?

Comment: e.g. val t=new x { this.a = this.a +1 }

Comment: @milo Technically that is creating an anonymous subclass of `A` and the code in braces is the constructor for that subclass. So, for example, it can't access private members of `A` but it can access protected members

Answer (score 1):

In scala primary constructor is created when you define a class. In your code also, var is created inside primary constructor.
More about constructor:

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-multiple-class-constructors-in-scala-alternate-constructors

Comment: Sorry, I can’t follow you. a=a+1 is an assignment operation and NOT sealed in any function declaration. Is this related to a constructor?

Comment: Yep this is a Scala way. Anything you write after class definition will be considered in primary constructor. To create secondary constructor you'll need to create this methods

Comment: Got it! Thank u!